# Parquet concat or split two schemes

Tags: bigdata, parquet, presto, file-format

I have two CSV files.  In the first one I have: `first_name`, `last_name` and in the second I have: `email`, `phone`. The two files connect by line index (same number of records). I need to save all data in parquet format.

First option - connect two schemes to one and save everything in one parquet file.

Second option - save two schemes separately (as two parquet files).

According to my use-case there is a high probability to take the second option (2 files). At the end I need to query data using various tools, most often using Presto.

Question 1- is it possible to pull data from two parquet files (let's say `select first_name, email`)?

Question 2- Will there be a difference in run times?

I have run some tests, but cannot come to an accurate conclusion...

Answer (score 0):

You can pull data from those two tables but you need to have some join keys in order to combine the records. If it is not there the you might have to use **row_number()** assuming data are in the same order in both the tables. Data size also matters here.

In big data world, denormalized format is the recommendation if you have to join those tables very frequently in your queries. This approach will give you better performance.